# Calculating percentile value from mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, normal-distribution, percentile

I have to write some code to calculate the 95th percentile from a databaset which is normally distributed. I am easily able to calculate the mean and the standard deviation, which define the distribution. However, from those two values alone, is it possible to determine the x value of the 95th percentile? If so, could someone help me with the mathematical formula, which I will then convert into code.

Comment: You're actually asking the opposite question in your title than in your question body!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question from your title "Calculating percentile value from mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution":

In practice one can do that (i.e. computing the [normal cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) $\Phi$) by converting the raw value to a [Z-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) (subtract the mean, then divide by std-dev) and then using a lookup table (sometimes called a Z-table) to convert the Z-score to percentile (well, to probability, for percentile multiply that by 100). Wikipedia has both the table(s) and [examples how to use them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table#Examples_of_use).

If one needs more precision than a lookup table would provide there are some numerical algorithms that can compute that. The one in [R's pnorm](https://homerhanumat.github.io/tigerstats/qnorm.html) is [based on](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html)

- Cody, W. D. (1993) Algorithm 715: [SPECFUN](https://www.netlib.org/specfun/) – A portable FORTRAN package of special function routines and test drivers. ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software 19, 22–32.

There are numerous others by relying on the simple [transformation from $\Phi$ to the error function (erf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function), for which one can find [numerous approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Numerical_approximations). The paper by Soranzo and Epure (see next section) also gives an approximation formula directly as $$ \Phi(x) \approx 2^{-22^{1-41^{x/10}}} $$

Or more legible: `2**(-22**(1-41**(x/10)))`. Note this relies on the symmetry $\Phi(-x) = 1-\Phi(x)$ to extend it over negative arguments while preserving low error.

---

In the body of your question you are asking the opposite problem: "is it possible to determine the x value of the 95th percentile?" That's possible too, in general that's called the inverse cumulative cumulative or more succinctly [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function), but for the normal distribution that function is just called [probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit), so that's the shortest word-like name for $\Phi^{-1}$. In R probit is implemented in [qnorm](https://homerhanumat.github.io/tigerstats/qnorm.html). The numerical implementation of that in R is based on

- Wichura, M. J. (1988) Algorithm AS 241: [The percentage points of the normal distribution](http://csg.sph.umich.edu/abecasis/gas_power_calculator/algorithm-as-241-the-percentage-points-of-the-normal-distribution.pdf). Applied Statistics, 37, 477–484.

Besides that, the probit has [a simple algebraic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit#Computation) that relates it to the inverse error function. And there are [some approximation formulas for the latter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Numerical_approximations) as well, e.g.

$$\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(x) \approx
  \operatorname{sgn}(x) \sqrt{
    \sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{\pi a} + \frac{\ln(1 - x^2)}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{\ln(1 - x^2)}{a}} -
    \left(\frac{2}{\pi a} + \frac{\ln(1 - x^2)}{2}\right)
  }.
$$ where

$$ a = \frac{8(\pi - 3)}{3\pi(4 - \pi)} \approx 0.140012.$$

Then:

$$\operatorname{probit}(p) = \sqrt{2}\,\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(2p-1).$$

If it needs spelling out, probit will give you the z-score from the probability $p$ (percentile divided by 100). To convert the z-score to your "x" you need to then apply the opposite of the z-score transformation, i.e. multiply by std-dev and then add the mean.

If you don't care much about accuracy, you can go old school and approximate the probit by logit, e.g. compute it as

$$\operatorname{probit}(p) \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}\,\ \ln\left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right).$$

The latter approximation gets pretty bad as $p$ gets high or low (i.e. it's best around 0.5).

Another good approximation for probit from a [recent paper by Soranzo and Epure (2014)](http://m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2014/ams-85-88-2014/epureAMS85-88-2014.pdf) is

$$\operatorname{probit}(p) \approx  \frac{10}{\ln 41}\, \ln \left(1- \frac{\ln \frac{-\ln p}{\ln 2}}{\ln 22} \right) $$

This has low error for $p \ge 0.5$, but one can use the symmetry $ \operatorname{probit}(1-p) = -\operatorname{probit}(p) $ for $p$ below 0.5.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm responding so late, but thank you very much for that detailed answer. It is actually very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the percentile by taking the integral of the PDF (probability density function) from negative infinity to your target value (for the right-hand value).

Here is the PDF function for a standard distribution:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\, e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$$

So to find the percentile of 3 sigma on a standard normal distribution ($\sigma = 1$, $\mu=0$) you can solve the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi1^2}}\, e^{-\frac{(x - 1)^2}{(2) (1^2)}} = 0.99865...$$

More information can be found on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Comment: Yes, obviously that is the idea. But I need a programatic way of doing this. An integral formula does not help me. I need some kind of pseudo code or step-by-step method that I can implement.

Answer (score 1):

For a normal distribution, if you have the mean and the standard deviation, then you can use the following to find the percentiles:

mean= 50th percentile

mean + sd = 84th percentile

mean +2sd = 97.5th percentile

Hope this helps!

P.S.: You could read about this more in detail here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking for. Surely there is some kind of Integral, or other equation that can give me what I am looking for?